# Jquery Drag and Drop .append to issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery's drag and drop in my web application. 
I'm looking to be able to drop my items in the div below, but have them appear above the other content.

My div where I'm dropping items:

```
<div id="viewbuilder" class="module">
<h3>View Builder</h3>
    <!-- This is where I want my dropped items to show -->
    <div class="ends_module">
        <a href="#" class="button"> Build </a>
    </div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div><!--ClearFix -->
    <!-- This is where the dropped items are currently showing -->
</div>
```

Below is the section of jQuery that I believe is causing the issue:

```
     var $list = $("ul", $viewbuilder).length ?
               $("ul", $viewbuilder) :
               $("<ul class='results ui-helper-reset'/>").appendTo($viewbuilder);
```

Is there another way to place content into the div, that would have the opposite effect of append? Maybe, append as first-child of div.module?

Comment: have you tried .prependTo() instead of .appendTo() ?

Comment: How about  [.prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/)

Comment: .prependTo() is a step in the right direction, however, it pushes the content above the h3. I was not clear in my question, the h3 has to keep it's position.

Comment: Nevermind, it's early. Thanks for the help, got what I wanted from you guys. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

try this:

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart

or there are some more options in jqueryUI

Comment: Thanks, but I've been through the options on Jquery ui, this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="viewbuilder" class="module">
  <h3>View Builder</h3>
  <div id="put_content_here"></div> <!-- Add this div -->
   <!-- This is where I want my dropped items to show -->
   <div class="ends_module">
      <a href="#" class="button"> Build </a>
   </div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div><!--ClearFix -->
   <!-- This is where the dropped items are currently showing -->
```

```
var $list = $("ul", $viewbuilder).length ?
           $("ul", $viewbuilder) :
           $("<ul class='results ui-helper-reset'/>").appendTo($viewbuilder);
```

Step one, create: $putcontent = #put_content_here
Step to, create the div#put_content_here, and place where you want content
Step two, replace .appendTo($viewbuilder) with .appendTo($putcontent)

Problem solved.